# Some keyboard Ctrl+[key] combos not working (+ left Ctrl water damage)

Tags: laptop, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, water-damage

Yesterday I had a couple of raindrops (really very little) land on my laptop's left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key, which I promptly wiped off the keyboard's surface. In short order, the signal from the key got locked on. I promptly turned off the laptop, popped the key off and cleaned up underneath, and left it drying.

Today the left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is totally dead. I'll have to open up the laptop and check that there's nothing iffy stuck in the circuits underneath. <del>But that's not the main issue here; the more acute glitch is this:</del>

<del>Right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and other keys all work fine. With this weird exception: CTRL combo with some upper row keys (W, R, Y, U, O) and left/right arrows will not register. (Tested also with PassMark KeyboardTest.) These keys work fine on their own, as well as in <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> combos.</del>

*[ Edit: The above issue has now automatically fixed itself. Suppose the circuits are clearing! ]*

Also: Randomly (twice so far, yet to use the laptop much) the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> signal gets stuck on, as was when the water damage first happened. Suppose this is an echo from a dirty left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> circuit that flicks on and off as the laptop heats up, or something like that. This gets fixed with a reboot.

<del>For right now, to get stuff done 'til I take the laptop apart, I'd like to hear your takes on what's causing the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> etc. combos that refuse to cooperate, and how to fix if possible.</del> (As note above, this works; though I'm still curious as to what exactly caused it, if anyone has theories.) Any additional tips are of course also welcome. OS is 64-bit Win7 and laptop is Asus X450J.

---

**Edit:** Some further notes. Booting into safe mode makes no difference here. I tried to uninstall the keyboard driver, as described in one helpful troubleshooter. That resulted in a beautiful BSOD on the next bootup(s), had to revert to last known good configuration to be able to boot up again. I don't have a spare keyboard to test with (to see if there's a software anomaly causing this), but for whatever it's worth, the OSK works fine with left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> combos.

Comment: I've seen anecdotal reports that it can take up to a week for a keyboard to fully drive out after a spillage.

Comment: Well that works for me actually, I'm off for a road trip shortly, back by weekend... Suppose leaving the screen open will help with the drying process. Let's see if we get another anecdote out of my 'puter, or if I'll end up doing a master clean over the coming weekend. ^_^

Comment: You might want to get some bags of silica gel to help it dry out :)

Comment: @DavidPostill if only that were an option where I live (Indonesia). Chances are by the time I find a shop in the nearby city that actually sells such exotic things, I'll have taken apart, cleaned and rebuilt my laptop thrice over. Some say you could use rice (which on the other hand is quite available), but seriously it was like four drops that landed in, I can't imagine it'd take too long for it to dry out with this 30°C heat on...

Comment: Depends on the humidity as well as the temperature ...

Comment: Right, is humid for sure, being the middle of a (particularly dry) rainy season. Humidity oscillating between 60-90% marks. Can't find a formula for humidity/temperature/evaporation ratio. Not that I have a point of reference for "how long to dry minute quantity of water from keyboard circuit" anyway. Wait and see, then! One day yet, when I'm bored senseless, I'll get a stock of old laptops and figure that one out. In the name of science, I hope to post the first result soon.

Comment: Good luck :) ...

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the key is still registering as being pressed and when the computer boots it does so with the key pressed and might be doing a strange interrupt type thing. This would cause all of the issues you are describing.

I would let the keys dry out a little more and if that does not work you can double check everything by plugging in a new keyboard to make sure that out initial conclusion wasn't completely wrong (like its a program causing this or something unrelated to the keyboard).

Comment: Since my keyboard works otherwise normally, do you mean that the interrupt thingy on boot-up would make it not register as being pressed, although it's sending a signal, until something (what?!) makes it re-activate? Unfortunately I don't have a spare keyboard handy, so I suppose I'll just let it dry out some more. Yeah, I was wondering if this might be a software conflict! If that's the case, it must have been somehow triggered by the left CTRL bust. (Booting into safe mode made no difference. Suppose I should also try with a boot disk. Added more info to the question.)

Comment: So the CTRL-combos are now working. Hopefully will still do when I next reboot. You reckon the left CTRL might resurrect by itself too? As in, should I keep waiting for a while more, or just open up the laptop and start cleaning. (Taking this piece apart is a serious PITA, done it a couple of times, would rather wait if chances are it makes a difference...)

Comment: It sounds like it may have needed more time to dry out. If you are not getting the interment ctrl key sticking that you where before then its probably working now.  You can pick up a new keyboard for cheep so that might be a better option to just replace it.